# sending data with the help of post method in ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am having a form with hidden field and want to send the value to another php page process the request and display it inside a div tag. But, AJAX doesn't seem to post the hidden field value
below is my form and ajax code

```
<form name='cc' method='post' onsubmit='return disp()'>
<input name='id' type='hidden' value='" . $id. "'/>
<input type='submit' name='btnr' value='Display' />
 </form>
 <script>
function disp(){
    var xmlhttp;    

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    var id=document.forms["cc"]["id"].value;
    xmlhttp.open("POST","fetch.php",true);

    xmlhttp.send(id);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
xmlhttp.send('id=' + urlencode(id));
```

You need to include the form element name, so that PHP can put that in `$_POST`.

You also need to put `return false;` at the end of `disp()`, to prevent normal form submission, which will reload the page.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console? Have you checked the Network tab of Developer Tools to see what is actually being sent?

Comment: if i use get method then everything works fine or if i use post method without ajax then also everything works fine but don't know what goes wrong if I use post method and ajax at a time

Comment: Updated the answer: you need to `return false`.

Comment: No, PHP does that automatically when filling in `$_POST`.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console? Have you checked the Network tab of Developer Tools to see what is actually being sent?

Comment: it just shows a green signal then POST then cart.php

Comment: You need to click on it to see the details

Comment: It says `cart.php`, not `fetch.php`?

Comment: array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "19" ["btnr"]=> string(11) "Display"

Comment: sorry it says fetch.php

Comment: Are you sure the form says `onsubmit='return disp()'`, not just `onsubmit='disp()'`? Because that var_dump means it's doing normal form submission, not AJAX, since we didn't send `btnr` in the AJAX call.

Comment: And you really added `return false` at the end of the `disp()` function?

Comment: ya, have added return false at the end of disp() and also have written onsubmit='return disp()' instead of onsubmit='disp()'

Comment: There must be something different between what you're really doing and what you're showing, because this should work with those fixes. If you put an `alert()` in the function, does it show up?

Comment: what i am doing is with the help of posted id am fetching a table from my database and displaying  it

Comment: It doesn't matter what you're doing. If it's not alerting, it means the `onsubmit` isn't working. And I can't see any reason for that. There's probably a typo somewhere in the actual code.

Comment: Can you provide the URL to your page?